# Prev/Next Slide puts a border around current 'Nav Preview below Main Carousel'

Tags: jquery, slick.js

**Using Slick-Slider:**

I have a main carousel with a mini 'NAV PREVIEW' below it. It looks like this:

[image: my slick-slider with nav preview below]([Imgur]

**What is working so far:**

When clicking on the nav preview all works well. The main carousel goes to whichever 'nav preview below' was clicked and the css border jumps to the clicked/current 'nav preview'.

**How It Works:**

I think it is achieved by moving the .slick-current class on both main carousel and nav preview below. So in jquery maybe removeClass() and addClass().

**The issue:**

When using the main carousel's prev/next arrows or swiping to go to prev or next slide, the 'nav preview below' does not update the current slide with css purple border due to the .slick-current class not being moved to the current on the 'nav preview below'.

**How the css border works so far:**

Currently, I have a css rule which is

```
.slider-nav .slick-current img {
  border: 1px solid #A279B6;
}
```

Since the class .slick-current works when clicking on the nav preview, then the border is applied. However this does not work when using the main carousel's prev/next arrows or swipe.

**How I tried to solve this:**

I tried using the slick-slider **onAfterChange()** event which takes a parameter (currentSlide). I use currentSlide to get the index of which slide is current.

Next, I get the current slide index of the 'nav preview' with

```
activeNavSlide = $(.slider-nav).slick('slickCurrentSlide');
```

Great! I can console.log and yes I see that when I click on the nav preview, the index's of both stay in sync. However changing from the main carousel reveals that the main carousel index changes while the nav preview does not...due to .slick-current not being moved to the prev/next preview.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-viewer').slick();
    // Mini Carousel Nav Preview
    console.log($('.slider-nav').children('div').length);
    if($('.slider-nav').children('div').length == 1) {
      $('.slider-nav').addClass('removeNav');
    } else if($('.slider-nav').children('div').length == 2){
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.carousel-viewer',
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
      });
    } else {
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.carousel-viewer',
        dots: false,
        // arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
      });
    }

    //Check to see if index's of both stay in sync
    $('.carousel-viewer').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    activeNavSlide =   $('.slider-nav').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
    activeNavSlide = currentSlide;
    if(activeNavSlide == currentSlide) {
      alert('Match!');
    }
    })
  });
</script>
```

I expect to be able to use the main carousel's prev/next arrows or swiping to move the .slick-current class on the 'nav preview below', and thus put a css border around the current synced index.

Your feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some jquery that solves my issue and works fine for now, but I'm sure there is a more efficient (dryer) way to write this code. Would love some feedback on how I can take this to the next level!

I had to account for dynamic conditions where I may have up to ten slides, so here is what I have so far that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel-viewer').slick();
    // Mini Carousel Nav Preview
    console.log($('.slider-nav').children('div').length);

    if($('.slider-nav').children('div').length == 1) {
      $('.slider-nav').addClass('removeNav');
    } else {
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: $('.slider-nav').children('div').length,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.carousel-viewer',
        dots: false,
        // arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
      });
    }

    // Sync both main slider and nav thumnail(s) slider
    $('.carousel-viewer').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {

      activeNavSlide =   $('.slider-nav').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
      activeNavSlide = currentSlide;

      console.log('mainSlide is: ' + currentSlide + ' navSlide is: ' + activeNavSlide);

      if($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 10) {

        // FOR TEN PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 9).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 9).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 9) {

        // FOR NINE PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 8).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 8).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if ($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 8) {

        // FOR EIGHT PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 7).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 7).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if ($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 7) {

        // FOR SEVEN PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 6).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 6).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if ($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 6) {

        // FOR SIX PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 5).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 5).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if ($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 5) {

        // FOR FIVE PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 4).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 4).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else if ($('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').length == 4) {

        // FOR FOUR PAGES
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 3).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide + 3).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      } else {

        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 2).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide - 1).removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.slider-nav .slick-track').children('div').eq(activeNavSlide).addClass('slick-current');

      }

    })

  });
</script>
```